# FFMPEG: filter_complex how do I duplicate one output pad to multiple input pads

Tags: ffmpeg

This SEEMS like it should be easy, but I can't figure out how to do it!

How do I do this?

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -filter_complex
    [0:v]some_transform(trim, etc.)[c1][c2];
    [c1]do_something[out1];
    [c2]do_something_else[out2]" ...
```

This doesn't work:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -filter_complex
    [0:v]some_transform[c1];
    [c1]do_something[out1];
    [c1]do_something_else[out2]" ...
```

I *CAN* duplicate input streams ([0:v], for instance), just not "pads"...VERY frustrating!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [split](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#split_002c-asplit) or [asplit](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#split_002c-asplit) filters to split the input into several identical outputs. split is for video, and asplit is for audio.

The filter accepts a single parameter which specifies the number of outputs. If unspecified, it defaults to 2.

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -filter_complex
"[0:v]some_transform(trim, etc.),split[c1][c2];
 [c1]do_something[out1];
 [c2]do_something_else[out2]" ...
```

Comment: Thanks! That's weird, I looked for a split filter, too...will check the docs again. Thanks!!!!

Comment: @MarkGerolimatos Which docs did you refer to?

Comment: The online ffmpeg docs. Might have been looking at the mux doc instead of the filter doc.